# How can I keep modifier of hotkey active in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

A media keyboard I'm using doesn't have a full set of keys, so I'm trying to map alternatives using AutoHotkey. Basically, I want to use the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key together with some other keys to simulate the missing keys. This is what I've done:

```
<^>!,::send {Home}
<^>!.::send {End}
<^>![::send {PrintScreen}
<^>!]::send {Insert}
```

However, if I want to do the equivalent of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (to select all text to the beginning of a line), this doesn't work as I'd hoped. I know I can put a `*` at the beginning of the line so that <kbd>Home</kbd> is still sent even when I'm holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but the problem is that I'd like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to still be active so that I get the equivalent of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Likewise, if I want to do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> then holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> doesn't have the desired effect.

I assume I could set up extra rules to catch those combinations, but surely there must be a way to just have AutoHotkey not discard whatever modifier I'm holding at the time I hit the hotkey so that whatever combination I use it'll work?

EDIT (2014-07-16):

Here is the latest version of my script, which includes comments that make it clear what I'm wanting to achieve. Everything in this script works except for the last line. For some reason, even though I'm trying to send Alt + PrtScn it gets treated as just PrtScn.

```
; Home ( by pressing AltGr + , )
<^>!,::send {Home}
; Shift + Home ( by pressing Shift + AltGr + , )
+<^>!,::send +{Home}

; End ( by pressing AltGr + . )
<^>!.::send {End}
; Shift + End ( by pressing Shift + AltGr + . )
+<^>!.::send +{End}

; Insert ( by pressing AltGr + [ )
<^>![::send {Insert}
; Shift + Insert ( by pressing Shift + AltGr + [ )
+<^>![::send +{Insert}

; PrtScn ( by pressing AltGr + ] )
<^>!]::send {PrintScreen}
; Alt + PrtScn ( by pressing LeftAlt + AltGr + ] )
<!<^>!]::send !{PrintScreen}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to remap? `AltGr` + `Shift` + `!` = `Shift` + `Home`? If would be nice if you specifically pointed out what output you expect for a given input.

Comment: I've added extra information to the original post.

Answer (score 3):

Using the {Blind} attribute will pass on the modifier keys.

e.g.

```
<^>!,::send {Blind}{Home}
```

See: [Send existing modifiers with a key in autohotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380171/send-existing-modifiers-with-a-key-in-autohotkey)

Comment: I've tried it out, but unfortunately as soon as I add {Blind} it stops the hotkey from working completely, i.e. no matter whether I hold Shift or not, pressing those keys then does nothing. Maybe {Blind} is incompatible with AltGr?

Comment: You are right, since you use the AltGr key, this modifier key will be sent too, screwing up the rest. An alternative would be to define hotkeys for every instance e.g. <^>!,::send {Home} and <^>!+,::send +{Home}

Comment: Indeed, thanks, that's what I've already done (see my latest update to the original post).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that some of the combinations I wanted to do with Autohotkey, involving the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, are not possible due to <kbd>AltGr</kbd> itself actually being a combination of <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>. Therefore, not all modifiers are available for use together with that key, and some of the AutoHotkey commands give unwanted/unexpected results when trying to use them together with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

The final version of the script I'm using with my new keyboard (the UK version of the Microsoft All-in-One Media Keyboard) is as follows:

```
; Set an initial state for the lock keys
SetCapsLockState, off
SetNumLockState, on
SetScrollLockState, off

; Home ( by pressing AltGr + , )
<^>!,::send {Home}
; Shift + Home ( by pressing Shift + AltGr + , )
+<^>!,::send +{Home}

; End ( by pressing AltGr + . )
<^>!.::send {End}
; Shift + End ( by pressing Shift + AltGr + . )
+<^>!.::send +{End}

; Insert ( by pressing AltGr + [ )
<^>![::send {Insert}
; Shift + Insert ( by pressing Shift + AltGr + [ )
+<^>![::send +{Insert}

; PrtScn ( by pressing AltGr + ] )
<^>!]::send {PrintScreen}
; Alt + PrtScn ( by pressing Alt + ] )
!]::send !{PrintScreen}

; Scroll Lock ( by pressing AltGr + \ )
<^>!\::send {ScrollLock}

; Pause/Break ( by pressing AltGr + p )
<^>!p::send {Pause}
; Win + Pause/Break ( by pressing Shift + Alt + p )
+!p::send #{Pause}
; Control + Pause/Break ( by pressing Shift + Ctrl + p )
+^p::send ^{CtrlBreak}

; Run Calculator ( by pressing AltGr + c )
<^>!c::Run Calc
```